# Passing ModelState to RedirectToAction into a ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How can I pass back the validation errors I find when using `DbEntityValidationException`

```
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        this.ModelState.AddModelError(validationError.PropertyName, 
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("AccessDetail", "Home", new { IDValue = access.ID });
            }
```

It appears that when I do this `RedirectToAction` my `ModelState` refreshes and I can not view the errors it found.

The AccessDetail populates a view model that has many different sources of data in it.  So passing just the **access** to the View does not work.

I was looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142107/redirecttoaction-after-validation-errors/6299329#6299329) but it didn't fit my needs as my view is populated with a ViewModel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RedirectToAction` helper method issues a `302` response to the client which makes the clients to issue a new **GET** request to the new url.

If you want to persist some data between these 2 requests, Use `TempData`.

```
TempData["Errors"] = yourListOfErrors;
return RedirectToAction("AccessDetail", "Home", new { IDValue = access.ID });
```

And in your `GET` action, read the TempData values and display it.

But If you do not want to do the RedirecToAction, You may simply return the viewmodel back to the view and if you have the ValidationSummary helper method, it will show the validation error messages.

simply use

```
return View(model);
```

Comment: I tried repopulating my ViewModel but the validation message is not displaying for @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DataManagementTeacher.TeacherAttr.LeaveNotes)